# AWS - How to send data records, one at a time, to a lambda? Looking for a more elegant way of doing this

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, records

I have a table on DynamoDB with around 5k records. At some point, a lambda will do a query on this table and probably get most of it's records.

After that i need to send those records, one at a time, to another lambda.

Considering that the lambda processing is a very simple, fast and cheap procedure, i think that is best to keep the microservice approach. What i am struggling with is finding what service(s) will help me acomplish what i said in the second paragraph.

Note1: I know that i can make a lambda to get those records and send one at a time to another lambda via aws sdk, in a loop. What i am looking for is a more elegant way of doing this, decoupling the records retrieval from the records dispatching to another lambda.

Note2: I know that DynamoDB has streams but as far as i read, those stream are only intended for inserts, updates and deletes. That's not my case.

Note3: I know that lambda functions will scale up to 100 (as far as i remember) by default. Either way, i will adjust that with AWS if necessary.

Note4: I read something about kinesis but as far as i understand i do not need to analyse anything on the data. My only need is to be sure that each record will be sent to another lambda for processing, that's it.

Only now i figured that i omitted the following notes from the original question (sorry for that, i really forgot):

Note5: The order of processing those records is not important

Note6: The processing must be done in parallel

Note7: Each record must be processed exactly once

Have a great day!

Juan

Comment: If this is an ongoing need, then perhaps you could write each DynamoDB record (or its key) as an SQS message and then have a Lambda that's run on a schedule. When that Lambda is invoked on the timer, it begins to retrieve messages from the SQS queue and do work. Not sure if you specifically need each record to be processed by a unique Lambda (if you do, why?)

Comment: Adding to @jarmod, lambda `context` object has a parameter called `get_remaining_time_in_millis`. If your second lambda function finishes processing one record, check if you have enough time to continue processing the next one. If yes, continue. Similarly, when you read a message from SQS, hide it for some time. That way your second invocation of Lambda function will not read this and if for some reason the processing fails, the message is back in the queue. Also SQS supports dead letter queues. So, if some message / event is missed, you can process them at a later time.